# Control video send framerate on the fly in webrtc

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Right now I use the b=AS:1000 in the offer SDP to set the upper limit(i.e. 1Mbps) for the upstream video to control the amount of video I am sending to the remote peer. I am looking into a different approach, so I was wondering if there is a way to control video frame rate on the fly of the current active video session?

**EDIT:**
I found out that getUserMedia supports minFrameRate and maxFrameRate parameters. So can I call getUserMedia while my peer connection is in session? Another similar use case, which  find reasonable, is to be able to change the camera while I am already in a peer session? Without having to renegotiate SDPs, ICE, ... Is this doable?

Comment: You may could do something with control packets but not through the browser.

Answer (score 19):

You're asking several questions, and when this answer was first written, the short answer to most of them was: **not yet** *(though I've since updated it thanks to DJ House's [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61736803/918910)!)*.

### applyConstraints

You should be able to alter constraints during an active session, using [applyConstraints](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#media-stream-track-interface-definition) like this:

```
const videotrack = stream_from_getUserMedia.getVideoTracks()[0];
videotrack.applyConstraints({ frameRate: { max: 10 } });
```

Most implementations today are able to decimate frame rates and not just deliver the modes available in the camera.

Try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g5zvzcw3/).

### RTCRtpSender

You should be able to control encoding & transmission in the sender object using [setParameters](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-rtcrtpsender):

```
const pc = RTCPeerConnection(config);

const videotrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
const sender = pc.addTrack(videotrack, stream);

// get the current parameters first
const params = sender.getParameters();

if (!params.encodings) params.encodings = [{}]; // Firefox workaround!

params.encodings[0].maxBitrate = 60000;
params.encodings[0].scaleResolutionDownBy = 2;
sender.setParameters(params);
```

`encodings` is an array, but unless simulcast is used, there's just one entry.

Try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kv14z7r6/)! (tested in Chrome, Firefox, Safari & Edge!)

### RTCRtpSender.replaceTrack

You should also be able to replace the camera track in an ongoing peer session, like this:

```
const videotrack2 = a_different_stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
await sender.replaceTrack(videotrack2);
```

It alters what the remote sees, without altering things at this end. Try it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8nem95k7/).

Comment: Any ideas how soon the future API will be here? 6months/1 year?

Comment: Some things have been implemented now in Firefox, so I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Safari mobile (iOS). I set scaleResolutionDownBy to 2 but it just ignores it. The code works in Chrome desktop though, so it's not the code.

Comment: Safari does not support 'scaleResolutionDownBy'

Comment: @jib What would you prefer cpu wise on the client machine having to deal with a few remote connections simultaneously: 1) 'applyConstraints' on the original stream? 2) change encoding with 'setParameter' on each rtpSender 3) open from the beginning two distinct streams (1 high res + 1 low res) and use 'replaceTrack' as needed to flip the streams.

Comment: @Dachstein I'd be surprised if it mattered, but I would measure. Web compat may be more important (E.g. Firefox still only returns native modes using constraints). See [my blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/fiddle-week-downscale-video-peerconnection/) for a Safari workaround.

Comment: @jib Thanks for the link, but 'scaleResolutionDownBy' does not work in Safari. Did I miss something? Regarding my previous question: I was thinking that initially open two/three distinct streams with gUM (enable=false for ones not in need) and flipping them with replaceTrack as needed should save cpu. Reasoning: Each stream gets fed into a rtpSender (Decoder) which needs to decode the stream according to 'setParameters'. Decoding a gUM 720p or a gUM 144p stream should make a difference on __each__ rtpSender. Are my thoughts reasonable? But you are right, it needs to be measured.

Comment: @jib Opening _one_ 720p stream fed into 5 rtpSenders each of them having to decode the stream down to what we have supplied in 'setParameters' ..or.. having _one_ 144p stream fed into 5 rtpSenders each of them dealing with a much lower resolution thus decode time/cpu time should decrease?

Comment: @jib sorry I meant Encoder/encoding of course not Decoder/decoding.

Comment: @Dachstein Here's the [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63331550/918910) I meant to link to for Safari (which doesn't support `scaleResolutionDownBy`). As to performance, you may be right or you may be wrong. MediaStreamTrack and RTCRtpSender are merely browser control-objects for media that's really flowing off-main-thread. I see no reason browsers can't optimize the  source-to-sink media path regardless of where in JS down-scaling is declared. But that doesn't mean they are doing that, of course. So best to 1) get it working, 2) measure, 3) optimize.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who ends up here like I did (5 years later), I needed to get the parameters before setting them. I am assuming since this was such an old question that the API just got a little out dated.

Without getting the parameters first, I always got this error:

`Failed to execute 'setParameters' on 'RTCRtpSender': required member codecs is undefined.`

Here's a quick way to get and manipulate the current parameters:

```js
var pc = RTCPeerConnection(config);

var videotrack = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
var sender = pc.addTrack(videotrack, stream);

// get the current parameters first
var params = sender.getParameters();

params.encodings[0].maxBitrate = 60000;
params.encodings[0].scaleResolutionDownBy = 2;

sender.setParameters(params);
```

This was still a great answer for me to quickly debug some Webrtc bandwidth related issues.

Comment: from mdn docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/setParameters#currently_compatible_implementation